how can I query the array of jsonb on supabase?
I have the column called users and {'user': 123, 'email': 'asjof@asdf.com}. I want to return the entire row that matches 123.
.eq("users -> user", 123)

I've tried this from https://www.reddit.com/r/Supabase/comments/vid5f9/comment/idkpyqe/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf&context=3. And,
  .select('*')
  .eq('users:jsonb->>user', 123)

from Supabase JSON query JavaScript
But nothing really works. How can I query the array of jsonb to find the row?
  .from("users")
  .select("*")
  . eq("users -> user", 123)
  )

The column users that has [{'user': 123, 'email': 'asjof@asdf.com}, {'user': 4234, 'email': 'asjofsijdoef@asdf.com}, ....]
I want to search all the rows that have user values of 123 in the users column

What array? What exactly is the type of the column, and where is the array value?

type of the column is ARRAY JSONB with {'user': 123, 'email': 'asjof@asdf.com}

Each rows have multiple user objects inside the users column. And, I want to return every rows that have user 123

Then you'd need to use ANY, but the general wisdom is to never use jsonb[] in the first place. Store a json array value in a normal jsonb column instead.

That is what I'd thought. I was going to use MongoDB for json like typed. Then they were like use join table. Then I ended up with 4-5 nested join table that I could not even trace it. So, I asked community about I don't think I can deal with the join table with my db. Then told me to use jsonb that supports index and stuff.

Yes, use jsonb. Don't use jsonb[].

If I put it to users JSONB, {list:[user....]}. How do I search that?

Easiest would be a json path I guess, users @? '$.*.user = 123'. Not sure how to write that with the supabase query builder though
